# css font face does not work awesomium.net

Tags: c#, css, wpf, font-face, awesomium

I use awesomium 1.7.5.1 (latest version until now) in WPF.
when I load a webite it works great, but when I load local html files, I have problem with css font-face. It doesn't work.
all of css,javascripts are working great, but only font face has problem.
What is the problem?I don't get result in Awesomium website.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved. I replaced another .woff font file and then it works

Answer (score 0):

First of all, please post your code so we can further understand the situation and how to help you fix it.

Second of all, in CSS3, which I am assuming is what you are working is, uses the code

```
@font-face {
    font-family: myFirstFont;
    src: url(sansation_light.woff);
}
```

*Taken from w3 schools*
[w3 schools](http://www.w3schools.com/)

you need to specify the url, and often using services, url's change and paths change. so make sure it is linking correctly.

Lastly, please specify what you are using. We dont all know what Awesomium is, whether it is a web server host, or a free online website maker, etc. Also to note, you added a tag `c#` along with `css` which honestly doesnt seem to make sense.

Comment: Awesomium is a HTML UI Engine based on webkit (http://awesomium.com) and you can use it instead of Webbrowser. I wrote font face as well as you wrote. it works on browser, but does not work on Awesomium